# error 4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Tags: c++, string, class

```
fndef FIXED_LENGTH_STRING_H
#define FIXED_LENGTH_STRING_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include <string.h>

template <int Length>
class FixedLengthString
    {
    public:
        enum Exceptions {InvalidLength};
                                        FixedLengthString       ();
                                        FixedLengthString       (const FixedLengthString <Length> &);
                                        FixedLengthString       (const char []);
                                        ~FixedLengthString      ();
                                        Copy                    (const FixedLengthString <Length> &);
                                        Copy                    (const char []);
        istream &                       Read                    ();
        FixedLengthString <Length> &    operator =              (const FixedLengthString <Length> &);
        FixedLengthString <Length> &    operator =              (const char []);
        bool                            operator <              (const FixedLengthString <Length> &) const;
        bool                            operator <              (const char []) const;
                                            // also need the other comparison operators
                                        operator const char *   () const;
    private:
        char    Data [Length + 1];
    };

template <int Length>
ostream & operator << (ostream & out, const FixedLengthString <Length> & Str)
    {
    // display the characters in the string
    return out;
    }

template <int Length>
istream & operator >> (istream & in, FixedLengthString <Length> & Str)
    {
    Str.Read ();
    return in;
    }

template <int Length>
FixedLengthString <Length>::FixedLengthString (const char S [])
    {
    if (Length != strlen (S))
            throw InvalidLength;
        else
            strcpy (Data, S);
    }

template <int Length>
inline FixedLengthString <Length>::operator const char * () const
    {
    return Data;
    }

#endif
```

The compiler is pointing at the two Copy constructors. I am creating a template with the number of characters as the template argument. From this I need a fixed length string

In my FixedLengthString.cpp file i have this

```
FixedLengthString<Length>::Copy(const FixedLengthString <Length> & M)
{
strcpy(Data, M.Data)
}

template <int Length>
FixedLengthString<Length>::Copy(const char M [])
{
strcpy(Data, M.Data)
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a duplicate, but @Axalo is right; you can only define templates in the header file.

Answer (score 1):

You only have *one* copy constructor, because there can only be one.

But you forgot the return type — `void` looks plausible — on your two *functions* called "Copy", so I suspect that you're referring to those.
But they're not constructors, just regular functions.

And you can't have template function implementations in a separate file, you must put them in the header.